# execute a function within a timer

Tags: android, class, timer

I ve got this function here:

```
public void stoprecording()
{
    this.recorder.stop();
    this.recorder.reset();
    this.recorder.release();
}
```

which stops the recoridng. This is within the class Audio. I also got this function here:

```
public void recordtimer(final int timer)
{
    /*First Part with timer*/
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            CountDownTimer countDowntimer = new CountDownTimer(timer, 100000) 
            {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

                public void onFinish() {

                    this.stoprecording();
                }
            };countDowntimer.start();
        }
    });

    thread.start();

    this.stoprecording();
}
```

also within the class Audio. I can´t execute this.stoprecording(); because the class CountDownTimer doesn t have this function. How can I execute this function?

Comment: Try `Classname.this.methodname();`. If your class name is `Audio` you have to write `Audio.this.stoprecording();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems there is no need to call `stoprecording()` from `this`, since it does not belong to `CountDownTimer` class you have defined.

Just call it like

```
public void onFinish() {

   stoprecording();
}
```

or if you want to definitely use `this`, follow the @gary111 suggestion thus doing

```
public void onFinish() {

   YourClass.this.stoprecording();
}
```